# Is there a way to fix my settings changing after opening a project in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So in my settings.json I change the setting(i.e. tab.activeBackground) and it works after saving. But then when I open a folder to code in... **the previous settings get restored**. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: change the **Global** settings, not the **Workspace** / **Folder** version

Answer (score 0):

Never mind solved it. I just deleted and rewrote my settings.json and it worked. It took a few minutes but... yeah. If anyone does have another way please still reply, **I have a feeling it's going to happen again.**